# C# override DependencyProperty mark as obsolete

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a custom WPF control that has a DependencyProperty:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DeferedVisibilityProperty;


    private static void OnDeferedVisibilityChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        var control = (CircularProgressBar)d;
        control.OnDeferedVisibilityChanged();
    }


    public bool DeferedVisibility {
        get => (bool)GetValue(DeferedVisibilityProperty);
        set => SetValue(DeferedVisibilityProperty, value);
    }


    private void OnDeferedVisibilityChanged() {
        if(DeferedVisibility) {
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Visible", true);
            Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        } else {
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Collapsed", true);
            Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
```

Now we can set visibility without bool-to-visibility converter.
When using the Visibility DependencyProperty it does not work any more, so i want to mark it as obsolete.

I know you can mark members like this `[Obsolete("Please use DeferedVisibility")]`.

**So how can I mark the Visibility Property of the base class as obsolete?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do override the Visibility dependency property:

```
[Obsolete("Use something else")]
public new Visibility Visibility
{
    get { return (Visibility)GetValue(VisibilityProperty); }
    set { SetValue(VisibilityProperty, value); }
}

[Obsolete("Use something else")]
public new static readonly DependencyProperty VisibilityProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Visibility), typeof(Visibility), typeof(YourCustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(0));
```

But the problem I see, is that obsolete will only be marked in code behind, not in XAML(at least by me)

Comment: This solution is nice, thanks.
I only override the Visibility Property because the DependencyProperty gives me an exception.
Luckily ReSharper resharper also markes the XAML code for me.